# Cannot get union Typing for generic?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So Here is some code i am working with.
I cant seem to make it work.

```
type someGeneric<T> = { a: T, b: (args: T) => void };

type abc = someGeneric<string> | someGeneric<number>;
type xyz = someGeneric<string | number>;
type someType = ? ;

const abc: abc = { a: 'someString', b: (args) => { } }; // args inferred as any;
const xyz: xyz = { a: 'someString', b: (args) => { } } // args inferred as string | number;

const someType: someType = { a: 'someString', b: (args) => { } }// args need to be inferred as string;
```

I am  not sure how to make this thing work.
Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in first case for `abc` the type of `args` can't be inferred because it could be a number or a string but can't be `string | number`. Which value is allowed is so long as it matches with `a`.

```
let validString: abc = {a:'someString', b: (args: string) => {} };
let validNumber: abc = {a: 1, b: (args: number) => {}};

let notValidabc: abc = {a: 1, b: (args: string)=> {}}; // this isn't allowed because a and args have to be both number or both string
let isvalidxyz:  xyz = {a: 1, b: (args: string)=> {}}; // this is allowed
```

there isn't a way to create a type which says "infer the generic type based on what this is assigned to" (as much I really want there to be) but you can write a very simple wrapper function so the constraints are specified in parameter type and stuff to infer in generics:

```
function makeThing<T>(thing: someGeneric<T>){
    return thing;
}

const thing = makeThing({a: 'somestring', b:(args)=>{}});
// args is inferred as string, thing is inferred as someGeneric<string>
```

---

Try [this case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20someGeneric%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20T%2C%20b%3A%20(args%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20abc%20%3D%20someGeneric%3Cstring%3E%20%7C%20someGeneric%3Cnumber%3E%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20with%20noImplicitAny%20flag%20this%20is%20invalid%20since%20args%20can't%20be%20infered.%0Aconst%20abc%3A%20abc%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20'someString'%2C%20b%3A%20(args)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20makeThing%3CT%3E(thing%3A%20someGeneric%3CT%3E)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20thing%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20thing%20%3D%20makeThing(%7Ba%3A%20'somestring'%2C%20b%3A(args)%3D%3E%7B%7D%7D)%3B%0A%2F%2F%20args%20is%20inferred%20as%20string%2C%20thing%20is%20inferred%20as%20someGeneric%3Cstring%3E) but set the `noImplicitAny` flag to true, you will see that it's not that args *is inferred as any*, it's that **typescript can't infer the type of args.**

```
const abc: abc = { a: 'someString', b: (args) => { } };
```

Typescript can only infer types when there is only one option for the type given the constraints, the constraints in your case is either `(arg: string)=>any` or `(arg: number)=>any`, since there are 2 options (and it can't use `string | number` since that isn't valid either(1))
it can't infer what it is.

In the other case where there is a function, typescript is instead looking to define the generic T based on the fields given, finds that `a` matches a string so uses that as T, then tries to infer type of `arg` based on T being a string.

(1): `string | number` isn't valid for `arg` because whole object can only conform to `someGeneric<string>` or `someGeneric<number>` at a given time, either case `string | number` isn't valid.

Comment: cool, makes sense,
I am not able to understand why in case `abc` `args` is inferred as any, you did mention it in the answer but i am not able to get my head around it,
it would be really helpful if you could provide an explanation for the same.

Comment: sorry, is that the type can't be inferred because there are multiple viable options given the surrounding context. The object literal needed to conform to either `someGeneric<string> | someGeneric<number>` but because we are just assigning to an object literal we don't know which of those we use when the type of `args` is checked so we can't infer. On the other hand with function parameter we look at the object literal, see that `a` is a string, now we know `T` then that gets applied to `args`.

Comment: @AmolGupta I don't think my initial response to your comment made a lot of sense, could you let me know if the amend to the answer is more helpful?